# Написать стили для фокуса

Tags: css3, html5

Возможно ли задать в `style` правила для фокуса, например `style="&.focus: border: 1px solid red;"`

Нужно именно это написать в `style=""`

Comment: нет. пишите css

Comment: Вы не можете использовать псевдокласс `:focus`внутри атрибута style. Если по каким-то причинам нужна инлайн-запись, то лишь вот так: `<input type="text" onfocus="this.style.border='solid 1px red'" onblur="this.style.border=''">`

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал css-свойство outline для элементов формы. А свойство border установил бы прозрачным во избежание, так сказать. Через запятую указал как focus указать для класса. По сути для этого примера это избыточно, можно было бы оставить только то, что до запятой или то, что после неё. Работать всё-равно будет корректно.

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}
input:focus, .myinput:focus {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" class="myinput">
</form>
```

А если нужны скругления border-radius, то используйте свойство box-shadow, благо, оно поддерживается большинством браузеров. ))

```css
input {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}
input:focus, .myinput:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" class="myinput">
</form>
```

Comment: окей а как через класс фокус показать

Comment: @svitalik1999gmailcom отредактировал ответ, чтобы указывался стиль и для класса тоже.

Comment: outline не дружит с border-radius

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov и для таких взыскательных пользователей есть своё решение ))) Добавил второй вариант в ответ.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что было не так со сменой цвета border и для чего в данном примере обходные варианты.

Но box-shadow действительно удобен тем, что можно 1) сделать по фокусу более толстую рамку без сдвига элементов, 2) помимо рамки добить эффект подсветки, например.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov Как-то так вышло, что `border: 1px solid red;` внутри `input:focus { ...` не сработало даже с отключенным outline. Есть мнение, может ошибочное, что такой вариант работает не для всех браузеров.